# PostgreSQL: retrieving multiple array elements

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Let's say we have a query like:

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_array('foo,bar', ',');
```

Results:

```
+-----------------------+
| regexp_split_to_array |
+-----------------------+
| {foo,bar}             |
+-----------------------+
(1 row)
```

To access a single element of an array we can use code like:

```
SELECT (regexp_split_to_array('foo,bar', ','))[1];
```

Which will return:

```
+-----------------------+
| regexp_split_to_array |
+-----------------------+
| foo                   |
+-----------------------+
(1 row)
```

Or use slices like:

```
SELECT (regexp_split_to_array('foo,bar', ','))[2:];
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------+
| regexp_split_to_array |
+-----------------------+
| {bar}                 |
+-----------------------+
(1 row)
```

However, when I try to access 2 elements at once, like:

```
SELECT (regexp_split_to_array('foo,bar', ','))[1,2];
```

or

```
SELECT (regexp_split_to_array('foo,bar', ','))[1][2];
```

or any other syntax, I receive an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
```

Is it possible to retrieve two different and not adjacent elements of an array in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting multiple elements through a select from an array should either mean you can have them returned as multiple columns or all those elements part of a single array.

This returns you one column as an array of the two elements.

```
knayak=# select ARRAY[arr[1],arr[2]] FROM regexp_split_to_array('foo,bar', ',') as arr;
   array
-----------
 {foo,bar}
(1 row)
```

..and this simply gives you the two elements as columns.

```
knayak=# select arr[1],arr[2] FROM regexp_split_to_array('foo,bar', ',') as arr;
 arr | arr
-----+-----
 foo | bar
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Alexound : you're welcome. If you found the answer please accept it. Accepted answers increases it's value and helps others seeking solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The colon ':' in the array indexer does allow you to access multiple elements as a from-thru.

```
select (array[1,2,3,4,5])[2:4]
```

returns

```
{2,3,4}
```

This would work in your example above, but not if 1 an 2 weren't next to each other.  If that's the case, the suggestion from @KaushikNayak is the only way I could think of.

Using your example:

```
SELECT (regexp_split_to_array('foo,bar', ','))[1:2]
```